# Ram full need external card to be

Tags: memory, sd-card

I have a Trio G4 tablet with 16gb of ram space. I have only 15 programs installed that are small.  All are in mb some in kb and my ram is full. How do I wipe out my ram? I have everything backed up and moved to the internal SD card which states that I have 11GB of storage available but with the ram being full I can't download anything. Plus I installed a 32gb external sd card  and my tablet tells me that it is mounted.  How do I  clear my ram and make my external sd card my default for downloads and what nots? Oh, and the sd card is compatible with my tablet.

Comment: Go here http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=Running+out+of+storage+memory The android stack exchange site, and use various search terms for running out of "application" memory or storage. Also do searches for the "error" you are presented, that information has been covered in a few different Q&As there.

Answer (score 2):

First off, I don't think you mean RAM. I've never heard of a tablet that has 16GB of RAM ([pcworld specs](http://www.pcworld.com/product/1430699/trio-stealth-g4-tablet.html) say it has 512 MB of (DDR3 SD)RAM). I think you mean flash. But anyway, If you need to clear the memory, just plug the tablet into your computer and you should be able to access your files from there. But if you really do mean RAM, then 1) that is one suped up tablet, and 2) A simple restart, either through the power button or the reset hole, should clear the RAM.